# jsoup parse() seems to drop leading <script> Element

Tags: jsoup

I have HTML that may contain an embed code from Surveymonkey that I wish to run through jSoup to make sure that the resulting HTML is valid. XSS is not an issue here. Here's a sample HTML snippet (edit: the content of the JavaScript is irrelevant in this case, so I have replaced the Surveymonkey JS with a simple log statement):

```
<script type="text/javascript">console.log('foo');</script>
<div id="somecontent">some content</div>
<script type="text/javascript">console.log('bar');</script>
```

A `parse(htmlSnippet).body().html()` results in a string that's missing the first `script`-block altogether:

```
<div id="somecontent"> some content </div> 
<script type="text/javascript">console.log('bar');</script>
```

The second `script`-block is not stripped, however.

If I prefix the whole thing with an empty `<span></span>`, jSoup keeps the `script`. So for the following snippet

```
<span></span>
<script type="text/javascript">console.log('foo');</script>
<div id="somecontent">some content</div>
<script type="text/javascript">console.log('bar');</script>
```

`parse(htmlSnippet).body().html()` returns

```
<span></span> 
<script type="text/javascript">console.log('foo');</script> 
<div id="somecontent">some content</div> 
<script type="text/javascript">console.log('bar');</script>
```

So obviously I must have something wrong here. Could anyone shed some light on the issue?

I could go and try Tidy for this purpose, but I'd rather have exactly one library for the job of correcting user errors in the markup and optionally cleaning using whitelist (which is not the issue here).

Comment: Please don't show us minified code

Comment: Can you make your script a little more readable?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the original post and replaced the original Surveymonkey JS with simple log statements. Actual JS content is irrelevant here, problem applies to just any leading script-block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by the JSoup dev himself, see [Github Issues](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/726).

Jonathan Hedley wrote:

> If you are parsing a body fragment, you should use the
>   Jsoup.parseBodyFragment() method. That forces all the content provided
>   into the body, instead of trying to create a full valid document.
>
> What's happening here is that you're asking Jsoup to parse a document.
>   Per the spec, a HTML document has a head and a body, and when parsing,
>   the first script goes into the head (because the body hadn't started
>   yet, and the script is OK in the head. Then the parser sees a div,
>   which can't go into the head, so it moves to the body. Once in body
>   mode, every tag is kept in the body.
>
> So in your span, the script goes into the body because the parser
>   had already switched to the body.
>
> Chrome and other HTML parsers do the same thing: [parsing result in
>   Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBuoa.png)